# Are the plastic bags inside the LEGO box recyclable?

Tags: packaging

Are the plastic bags inside the LEGO box recyclable?

Also, why aren't the plastic bags inside the box not completely filled? If The LEGO Group didn't want it completely filled then why not decrease the bag size?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! The people answering questions here are mere fans of LEGO, not actual LEGO employees - you'd do better asking your question via [the official LEGO support site](https://wwwsecure.us.lego.com/en-us/service). Good luck with your FLL challenge!

Comment: I would say that they do this so that the bags don't pop open. This would be the most logical answer

Comment: If you lay the bags flat and spread out the pieces, they *do* fill the bags. When put in bags that can be flatter (but use more plastic), it means thinner boxes can be used, which reduces paper used. TLG actively tries to reduce box size and other resource uses to move towards more green practices.

Comment: Generally the question in the title and the question in the body should match. It makes it much easier to find answers when searching. This would be better asked as two questions.

Comment: In 2020, LEGO is working on moving to paper bags to replace the single-use plastic.  https://www.lego.com/en-us/aboutus/sustainable-packaging/

Answer (score 11):

According to [this bricksetforum thread](http://www.bricksetforum.com/discussion/1274/recycling-lego-plastic-bags-5) (and also true of the LEGO sets we have around right now) the LEGO bags are [#5 plastic](http://www.babygreenthumb.com/p-122-safe-plastic-numbers-guide.aspx) which is accepted by [Whole Foods](http://www.wholefoodsmarket.com/stores/list) and some municipal recycling services.

[This thread](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/452/is-there-a-logic-to-the-way-the-lego-group-fills-the-plastic-bags)
has interesting commentary on bag packing considerations.  Not surprisingly LEGO Group is optimizing for efficiency and dependability.  The bags and their weight also affect the QA process which includes weighing the bags.

### 2021 update - the future is getting here

LEGO is [reportedly moving to paper bags](https://www.greenmatters.com/p/legor-plastic-bags-paper).  This is a double win of going with a renewable resource and wider recycling availability.  LEGO themselves have a page on their [sustainable packaging](https://www.lego.com/en-us/aboutus/sustainable-packaging/) that says:

> We will begin to test paper bags in our boxes which means goodbye single use plastic and hello recycling bin! First, we will trial recyclable paper bags that are made from Forest Stewardship Council certified paper. They will be designed to help children understand the importance of recycling and ensure they have the best possible play experience. Our new bags will be phased in over a four-year period from 2021.

Answer (score 2):

No, the bags are actually not recyclable, and the bags aren't filled entirely because TLG wants the bags to be more flexible and loose,so they fit easily in the bags!